# jupyterlab terminal commands executed in wrong environment

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I can install all dependencies of my python functions in a `conda` environment and then run the commands in `Python` script in the terminal, but when the bash commands are executed via `os.system(...)` inside a Jupyter notebook they are not found, or the wrong version is used. Is there a way to run all bash commands with `os.system()` and using the e.g. `! ls -artl` in the currently active conda environment.

I have multiple conda environments and installed the kernels via `ipykernel install --user ...`.

Now, I can select the different `Python` kernels for different notebooks.

I tried adding `conda activate my_env ; ...` to my bash commands and `sys.syspath.append(path_to_env_bin_folder)`.

Both did not work.

Using JupyterLab 3.0.14

UPDATE: This seems to be a JupyterLab issue. I can run the same code with VSCode and it finds all the necessary dependencies. I hope this gets fixed in future versions of JupyterLab.

Comment: There is a work in progress on this I believe here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/10203. You can help testing out this PR for it to be included in 3.1

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing. It does not seem to be the same problem. I want to have the commands executed with `os.system()` in a jupyter notebook to know which environment to use. The PR seems to be about multiple terminals instead.

Comment: Right, sorry, the terminal in title mislead me when I skimmed the question.